# going to cross black to white wire,... but which one?

Tags: electrical, wiring

So I replaced all of my fire detectors. They were hard wired with battery backup, and so are the new ones... accept for one. I put the wireless combo CM and fire detector in the ceiling of my common 2nd floor area.

[image]

So after disconnecting the old wired detector from the white/black/red wires, I lost power to one outlet in an adjacent bedroom and the light in the 2nd floor area directly next to the detector. The light is controlled by 3 switches in same hallway.

So now Im left with these wires and I am betting I have to cross a black and white, but which one? all of them perhaps?

Comment: if someone can tell me how to add a picture I will.

Comment: Please read the posting guidelines, and also try reading the help info.   In particular, you need to tell us what "these wires" are and what method of disconnecting you used.  You should have left the  connector in place (with white, black, red wires feeding it); looks like you didn't.  Whatever you do, don't connect a black, hot,  to a white, neutral!

Comment: Since you are new you will have to put the photo on a another sharing site and put the location in your question and someone with more rep will edit it in.  The only time you see white as a hot is on a switch loop. As Carl said we never just switch them without knowing what we are doing.

Comment: There's no reason your other circuit nodes shouldn't work if you have good connections. Check for loose wires in the nuts. My guess is that one black-white pair branches off the detector circuit for those other things.

Comment: Also consider that the problem may not be in that box, but in a previously-modified one.

Comment: Yeah I checked all the connections in every box upstairs, including this one, untwisted everything and twisted it back up. Im starting to think the breaker might have gone bad but its clicking all the way into place... I dont know, I guess the next cheapest solution is to buy a wired unit and put it back the way it was and see if that helps.

Comment: Your photo doesn't show us how the smoke detector wired into those clusters.  can you show/explain that bit?

Comment: I just wired back in the smoke detector like it was before and it did not fix the problem. I am going to try and swap a breaker to see if that is the issue, unless there is a better idea?

Comment: the smoke detector wired in red/red white/white black/black.

Comment: well no luck, all breakers tested at 120v... guess ill go back and open every detector box in the house and triple check that. Any chance one of the three light switches could be the culprit? Not passing electricity through to the dead outlet AND light?

Comment: eureka! finally found the problem. Started pulling wires in every bedroom... found a frayed wire after cutting back black strand in adjacent bedroom some detector box... must have been pretty bad before I changed the detector and the extra movement finally separated the copper. Well its fixed! thanks!